# Add one Row to Binary Tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

Here is the recursive code for adding one row in a binary tree at a particular depth "d" and  value of row nodes as "v" , however if I change the post increment of "depth" (I have marked the code) to pre-increment  , the code doesn't work for all testCases...Can someone pls explain? Thanks

```
public class Solution {
int value=0;
public TreeNode addOneRow(TreeNode root, int v, int d) 
{
    value=v;
    if(d==1)
    {
     TreeNode roott=new TreeNode(v);
     roott.left=root;
        return roott;
    }
    return solve(root,1,d);

}

TreeNode solve(TreeNode root,int depth,int at_depth)
{

    if(root!=null)
    {
        solve(root.left,++depth,at_depth);

        if(depth==at_depth)
        {

            TreeNode left_child=root.left;
            TreeNode right_child=root.right;
            root.left=new TreeNode(value);
            root.right=new TreeNode(value);
            root.left.left=left_child;
            root.right.right=right_child;


        }
                          ////HERE //////

        solve(root.right,depth++,at_depth); //correct code

///////here  "solve(root.right,++depth,at_depth) " is giving wrong solution////
        }
    return root; 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Let we are going to insert value 2 at depth 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrR2R.png) in this tree.
so the solve function call order will look like this

solve(node(8),1,2)

```
solve(node(5),2,2)
    solve(node(9),3,2)//at this level depth is 3
            ---here null check and recursive call ends
    solve(node(7),3,2) // depth will be passed as 3 when you put post-increment that is correct, 
    //But if you put pre-increment the depth will be 4 that is incorrect[solve(node(7),4,2) <-- wrong call].
```

Comment: Ty for the example

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with incrementing your variable `depth`.

As you are using the pre-increment operator, it changes the value of that variable, because of which the second time when you call `solve()`, you already have the incremented value of `depth`. So, if you try to increment it again using `++depth`, will give in unexpected results.

Instead of using the post/pre increment operators in the recursive call, you should use `depth+1` in both the calls and this will solve your problem.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Understood...Ty